# Getting low test accuracy using Tensorflow batch_norm function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the official Batch Normalization (BN) function ([tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100)) of Tensorflow on the MNIST data. I use the following code for adding BN:

```
local4_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(local4, is_training=True)
```

During testing, I change "is_training=False" in the above line of code and observe only 20% accuracy. However, it gives ~99% accuracy if I use the  above code also for testing (i.e., keeping is_training=True) with a batch size of 100 images. This observation indicates that the *exponential moving average and variance* computed by [batch_norm()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100) are probably incorrect or I am missing something in my code.

Can anyone please answer about the solution of the above problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get ~99% accuracy when you test you model with `is_training=True` only because of the batch size of 100.
If you change the batch size to 1 your accuracy will decrease.

This is due to the fact that you're computing the exponential moving average and variance for the input batch and than you're (batch-)normalizing the layers output using these values.

The `batch_norm` function have the parameter `variables_collections` that helps you to store the computed moving average and variance during the train phase and reuse them during the test phase.

If you define a collection for these variables, then the `batch_norm` layer will use them during the testing phase, instead of calculating new values.

Therefore, if you change you batch normalization layer definition to

```
local4_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(local4, is_training=True, variables_collections=["batch_norm_non_trainable_variables_collection"])
```

The layer will store the computed variables into the `"batch_norm_non_trainable_variables_collection"` collection.

In the test phase, when you pass the `is_training=False` parameters, the layer will re-use the computed value that it find in the collection.

Note that the moving average and the variance are not trainable parameters and therefore, if you save only your model trainable parameters in the checkpoint files, you have to manually add the non-trainable variables stored into the previously defined collection.

You can do it when you create the `Saver` object:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_trainable_variables() + tf.get_collection_ref("batch_norm_non_trainable_variables_co‌​llection") + otherlistofvariables)
```

In addiction, since batch normalization can limit the expressive power of the layer which is applied to (because it restricts the range of the values), you should enable the network to learn the parameters `gamma` and `beta` (the affine transformation coefficients described in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)) that allows the network to learn, thus, an affine transformation that increase the representation power of the layer.

You can enable the learning of these parameters setting to `True` the parameter of the `batch_norm` function, in this way:

```
local4_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
    local4,
    is_training=True,
    center=True, # beta
    scale=True, # gamma
    variables_collections=["batch_norm_non_trainable_variables_collection"])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am saving file using the command: 
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)
I do not see any option to save non-trainable parameters using save(). Can you please let me know how to save and restore non-trainable parameters?

Comment: When you create the saver you can specify the variable to save. saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_trainable_variables() + tf.get_collection_ref("batch_norm_non_trainable_variables_collection") + otherlistofvariables)

Comment: I have followed the solution (added variable_collection and saved non-trainable parameters), but yet observe the same problem. However, I have used the batch_norm_wrapper() function of [this](http://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html) and it worked perfectly in both train and test although I did not explicitly save the non-trainable parameters.

Comment: I don't know. [here](https://github.com/galeone/pgnet/blob/master/pgnet/model.py) I defined a batch_norm layer wrapping the tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm method and I used it (in the train.py file in the parent directory) as I told you and it worked. Maybe you can give a look at my source code to find the difference between your and mine implementation

Comment: Thanks @nessuno for sharing your code, which eventually helped me to find the missing element. It was necessary to add `scale=True` to solve the problem. 

In your code the default for **scale** is **True**, whereas in the original code it is set to **false**. Besides, I think I should set `updates_collections=None` for in-place update of the parameters. For the saving issue, I think default saver `tf.train.Saver()` saves all (trainable and non-trainable) the variables.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your answer so that it contains the complete solution of the problem and thus the answer can be acceptable.

Comment: You're right. I improved the answer with the `Saver` part and a little explaination of the `beta` and `gamma` parameters (respectively `center` and `scale` parameter of batch_norm layer)

Comment: Could there be another parameter that needs to be set in order to tell batch_norm to use the variables_collections?  I've implemented the suggestion here and I get the same results with or without the variables_collections.  Also, would you need a separate variables_collections variable name for each batch_norm layer? or will TF store all the variables in this collection?

Comment: I still use batch norm applied as I told to Hasnat and works. By the way no, you don't need a separate collection for each layer, tensorflow handles it for you (it will be untractable in a very deep layer)

Comment: Thanks @nessuno, good to know.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then.  I've also attempted the [batch_norm_wrapper](http://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html) technique and am getting exactly the same results between train/test as I am with contrib.layers.batch_norm.  I'm using conv2d layers, but not sure why that would make a difference.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue even after following this advice. Adding batch_norm has drastically improved the rate the loss function decreases at, however at test time I'm getting zero accuracy. If I remove batch_norm the loss decreases much slower, but I have some accuracy. Is there any you can look at the variable_collections and compare test-time and train-time sets? There has to be something wrong with my implementation, but I have no clue.

Comment: tf.get_trainable_variables() gives me error 'module' object has no attribute 'get_trainable_variables

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same question when processing MNIST. My train acc is normal, while test acc is very low at the begining, and then it grows gradually.

[image]

I changed default momentum=0.99 to momentum=0.9, then it works fine
My source code is here:

[mnist_bn_fixed.py](https://github.com/huosan0123/Tensorflow-study/blob/master/mnist_bn_fixed.py)